# Formula to test if value is in an array

Tags: formula, formula-field

Is there way to create a formula to check membership in a list?  Something like this:

MailingCounty IN ["Belgium", "France", "Germany"]

I need to create a formula field that will be TRUE if the MailingCounty is in the EU and FALSE otherwise.

Comment: Honestly, the downvotes? A CASE statement is a programming language construct. It is not the same as checking membership in a list. This is a legitimate question and the answer is NO - SFDC formula language cannot test for list membership.

Answer (score 3):

It's a pretty common scenario. The canonical approach is to use **[`CASE`](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_case.htm&type=5)**.

```
1 = CASE(
    MailingCountry,
    "Belgium", 1,
    "France", 1,
    "Germany", 1,
    0
)
```

Comment: typo -- `CASE(MailingCountry,`